# Can updatedb keep localpaths for removable drives that aren't plugged in?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, locate, updatedb

I run updatedb like this: `updatedb --localpaths="/a /b"`

`/a` is a removable drive. `/b` is the local hard drive. Although `/a`'s not always accessible to me, I frequently want to run `locate` to find if I have a certain file on it (based on the last time I ran `updatedb`).

The problem is, if I run `updatedb` when it's not plugged in, I get an error:

```
/usr/bin/find: '/a': No such file or directory
```

The database gets the latest information about `/b`, but it removes `/a`'s existing data. Is there a way to keep `/a`'s data when `/a` isn't plugged in during `updatedb`?

I think this might be possible with multiple databases, one for `/a` and another for `/b`. Then a script can check whether or not `/a` is plugged in when it decides whether or not to `updatedb`.

But the man page for both commands kind of assumes I know a lot more than I do (e.g., what `FINDOPTIONS` does), so I'm hoping there's an easier solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Linux on Windows, nor the GNU version of `locate`, but you should be able to do what you want. There is a longer version of the manual [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html).

Replace your single `updatedb --localpaths="/a /b"` by 2 commands,

```
updatedb --localpaths="/b"
if [ -d "/a" ]; then updatedb --localpaths="/a" --output=/dir/mydb; fi
```

where `/dir/mydb` is the full pathname of the file you want to hold the database in.

When you do a locate, set the environment variable `LOCATE_PATH` to `/dir/mydb::`. In principle `::` should mean use the standard db.

If `::` doesnt work, you may be able to get the filename of the standard db by running `updatedb --help`. It might say, for example, the default is `/usr/local/var/locatedb`. You can then set `LOCATE_PATH=/dir/mydb:/usr/local/var/locatedb` . You can also use the `-d` option to `locate` to provide this list of dbs.

Comment: `::` worked as advertised, FWIW. Thanks for the help

Comment: Oh yeah. I wanted to know if that longer version of the manual is accessible through a local command? I often end up asking questions here because I don't know how to find anything as thorough as your link. In fact, "Find utils" is the last place I'd think to look for information about `locate` and `updatedb`. How does one go from the man page of these commands to discovering your link without posting a question on stack overflow along the way?

Comment: Actually, the "find utils" page is a rare example of collected help on a subject. Sometimes, an http link is mentioned at the bottom of a man page, but probably not in this case. I don't remember how I found it initially, but I always keep short notes on commands when I use them for the first time, and the notes grow over time as snippets of info get discovered, often by reading answers on stackexchange. It's a slow process.